# How to choose an abbreviation for a given word?

Tags: nouns, abbreviations

I was trying to find a proper abbreviation for the word *dictionary*.
*Dict.* or *Dic.* or something else?

Obviousely there won't be a short form for each English word. But if there does exist one, how can I find it? Is there a rule of thumb for choosing the right abbreviation for any given word?

Answer (score 2):

Like I said under Snumpy's answer as a comment, I've always seen *Dict.* as an abbreviation for *Dictionary*.

On my NOAD:

> **Dict.** *abbreviation*
>
> - Dictation;
> - dictionary.

If I find more references, I'll make sure to post them.

Answer (score -2):

The key to abbreviations is that the reader knows what it means, so you could arguably use any abbreviation that would be clear to your reader(s).

In your particular case, the standard abbreviation is [*Dic*](http://www.abbreviations.com/bs.aspx?st=DICTIONARY&SE=2), and others can be found at [the same site](http://www.abbreviations.com).

Comment: Weird, I've always seen Dict for Dictionary... It seems even less ambiguous.

Comment: Is the period sign necessary or just optional?

Comment: That link you give says that the abbreviation *DIC* is a computer filename extension (and presumably this is why it has only three letters). A quick (though far from comprehensive) google suggests that *dict* is a more common abbreviation for dictionary.